# Math for a 2d explosion in java

Tags: java, 2d, particles

I'm making a game in java and I need a bit of help with particle effects. Can someone give me some advice, a formula or code to help me code an explosion?

Comment: I don't know how to *2d explosion*, but here is a *1d explosion*: `*`.

Comment: no, but there is a 3d explosion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jmonkeyengine.org/ can be usefull. I didn't use it but actually but there are some examples like http://env3d.org/beta/node/238

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this](http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series2D/Particles.php) tutorial can get you started on this topic. It is written for C# but it can be used for Java.